# How would I assign the list of operators so that the random numbers are worked out to tell the user if they're correct or not?

Tags: python

How would I assign the list of operators so that the random numbers are worked out to tell the user if they're correct or not?

```
    # Controlled Assessment - Basic Times Table Test
import random

score = 0

print ("Welcome to the times table test")

name = input("Please type your name: ")


print ("How to play")
print ("Step 1: When you see a question work out the answer and type it in the space.")
print ("Step 2: Once you have typed your answer press the enter key.")
print ("Step 3: The program will tell you if you're right or wrong.")
print ("Step 4: The next question will load and you can repeat from step 1.")
print ("When you have answered all 10 questions your final score will be    printed.")




for q in range(10):
    Number1 = random.randint(1,12)
    Number2 = random.randint(1,12)
    ListOfOperator = ['+','-','*']
    Operator =random.choice(ListOfOperator)
    print ('what is' ,Number1,Operator,Number2)
    Answer= input ("Please Type Your Answer: ")

realanswer = (Number1,Operator,Number2)

if ListOfOperator:
    ListOfOperator=['+'] = Number1+Number2
    ListOfOperator=['-'] = Number1-Number2
    ListOfOperator=['*'] = Number1*Number2




if Answer==realanswer:
    print("Your answer is correct")
    score = score + 1
    print (score)
else:
    print("Your answer is incorrect, the correct answer is.",realanswer,".")
    print (score)
```

The code that needs to assign to the list of operators is...

```
    if ListOfOperator:
    ListOfOperator=['+'] = Number1+Number2
    ListOfOperator=['-'] = Number1-Number2
    ListOfOperator=['*'] = Number1*Number2
```

It should work out the answer to each question using the function I'm telling the program that if the operator from the operator list is * to work out Number1*Number2

The current output for telling them if the answer is correct or not prints

> Your answer is incorrect, the correct answer is Number1*Number2.

when if the question is what is 10*3 it should be printing

> Your answer is incorrect, the correct answer is 30.

---

Now that I have this code...

```
if Operator == '+':
    realanswer = Number1+Number2
elif Operator == '-':
    realanswer = Number1-Number2
elif Operator == '*':
    realanswer = Number1*Number2




if Answer==realanswer:
    print("Your answer is correct")
    score = score + 1
    print (score)
else:
    print("Your answer is incorrect, the correct answer is.",realanswer,".")
    print (score)
```

The program always prints that the question is incorrect even with the correct answer inputted, it will then print the correct answer, how would I make it so that It would tell them if it's correct too?

Answer (score 1):

The `operator` module implements basic operations as functions. Define a `dict` that maps operator symbols such as `"+"` to the operator function then use that map to do the calculation.

```
import random
import operator

op_map = {'+':operator.add, '-':operator.sub, '*':operator.mul}
op_list = list(op_map.keys())

score = 0

print ("Welcome to the times table test")

name = input("Please type your name: ")

print ("How to play")
print ("Step 1: When you see a question work out the answer and type it in the space.")
print ("Step 2: Once you have typed your answer press the enter key.")
print ("Step 3: The program will tell you if you're right or wrong.")
print ("Step 4: The next question will load and you can repeat from step 1.")
print ("When you have answered all 10 questions your final score will be    printed.")

for q in range(10):
    Number1 = random.randint(1,12)
    Number2 = random.randint(1,12)
    Operator =random.choice(op_list)
    print ('what is' ,Number1,Operator,Number2)
    while True:
        try:
            Answer= int(input("Please Type Your Answer: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Must be an integer... try again...")

    realanswer = op_map[Operator](Number1, Number2)

    if Answer==realanswer:
        print("Your answer is correct")
        score = score + 1
        print (score)
    else:
        print("Your answer is incorrect, the correct answer is.",realanswer,".")
        print (score)
```

Answer (score 0):

To perform multiple check like this you can use if, elif statements:

```
if Operator == '+':
    realanswer = Number1+Number2
elif Operator == '-':
    realanswer = Number1-Number2
elif Operator == '*':
    realanswer = Number1*Number2
```

For your reference: [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=statement)

Answer (score 0):

```
...

def realanswer(Num1, Op, Num2):
    return {
        '+': Num1 + Num2,
        '-': Num1 - Num2,
        '*': Num1 * Num2,
    }[Op]

for q in range(2):
    Number1 = random.randint(1,12)
    Number2 = random.randint(1,12)
    ListOfOperator = ['+','-','*']
    Operator =random.choice(ListOfOperator)
    print ('what is',Number1,Operator,Number2)
    userInput = input("Please Type Your Answer: ")
    Answer = 0
    try:
        Answer = int(userInput)
    except ValueError:
        print("Input not convertible to int!")
    rAnswer = realanswer(Number1,Operator,Number2)
    if Answer == rAnswer:
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print("Incorrect...")
```